# Uniform random triangles in the square.

Tags: geometry, random-variables, triangles

Select $3$ points in the unit square $[0,1]^2$ randomly using the uniform distribution.

That gives you a triangle.  What is the expected distribution of edge lengths and internal angles?

You could ask the same question for $4$ points in $[0,1]^3$ giving a tetrahedron, etc.

My presumption is this is known, but I do not know where to look.

Comment: With three edges and three angles, this will give you a distribution in $[0,\sqrt{2}]^3\times[0, \pi]^3$ but not a density or a simple support.  Is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, and to make the edge lengths and angles well defined I mean to take the shortest edge length, 2nd shortest, and longest in that order.  You could in principle order the points and then talk about the edge lengths between the indexed points, i.e. the length between point 1 and 2, etc.  That's a less interesting question for me.

Comment: Simulation would give a quick answer to particular questions

Comment: I've done some simulations.  I'm curious if anyone knows the exact answer.

Comment: Have a look at Santalo's book on Integral Geometry, it does a lot of this kind of thing.

Comment: @Paul thanks, I will check it out.